# Chrome is not opening the url by using GoToUrl Method

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace SeleniumAuto_test_
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            IWebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
            d.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            IWebElement e = d.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            e.SendKeys("automation");

        }
    }
}
```

I have added the package of Selenium Web driver & WebDriverChromeDriver for this project online through NuGet packages. I have testing it out but its only opening the Chrome and nothing else is working! The test case is failing again and again. I have tried adding reference by downloading them from Selenium-HQ web page too.
Help will be appreciated.:)

Comment: Do you receive any error messages?

Comment: No!!
Nothing at all.

Comment: When you step through the code, what happens?

Comment: It is only opening Chrome and nothing else is there. Its not even putting url in the bar..

Comment: If nothing is happening, at some point your program will throw an exception, because that's what happens when you try to find an element on a page that you haven't navigated to. So what is the exception you're getting? My guess is its something related to setting the chromedriver location :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple things I would do to debug the issue:

- Run the test in debug until the full error / stack trace is returned so we can better answer the question.
- Attempt to perform another command on the chromeDriver, i.e. something like `driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();`, this will tell you if the GoToURL() method is the issue, or the instantiation settings for the ChromeDriver itself. If that doesn't work either you may need to experiment with instantiating the WebDriver in another way, by passing in ChromeOptions for example.
- Attempt to run the GoToURL() method more than once, is it possible that the web browser is somehow not in focus? (this is more of a grasping at straws kind of debugging step, but it never hurts to try)